# Javascript: Show .div if two inputs have a value of x or y

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs and a `div`. I would like to be able to show the `div` when *both* of the inputs have a value of 6 or 7.

I'm new to javascript. This is as close as I've been able to come (which isn't, I fear, all that close):

```
var div = $('div').hide();
$('.first, .second').keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value == 6 || value == 7) {
       div.fadeIn();
    } else {
      div.fadeOut();   
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P69Vg/1/)

Comment: so what is the problem? see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qgf34/1/

Comment: pls go through this...
http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/P69Vg/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.first, .second').keyup(function() {

   var value1 = $(".first").val();
   var value2 = $(".second").val(); 
    if ((value1 == 6 || value1 == 7) && (value2 == 6 || value2 == 7))  {
       div.fadeIn();
   } else {
      div.fadeOut();   
   }
});
```

Try the above

Comment: `if (Math.abs(value1+value2-13)+Math.abs(value1-value2)==1)` strange and elegant, but works too: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/P69Vg/17/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/P69Vg/7/)

HTML

```
<div>hello</div>

<input type="text" class="myinput" name='first'/>
<input type="text" class="myinput" name='second'/>
```

js

```
var div = $('div');
div.hide();

$('.myinput').keyup(function() {

    var value = 0;

    $('.myinput').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 6 || $(this).val() == 7 )
        {
           value = $(this).val();
        }
    });
    if(value == 6 || value == 7)
        div.fadeIn();
    else
        div.fadeOut();
});
```

CSS

```
div {
   border: 4px solid #333;  
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

all input must be 6 or 7 then to show the div, even if more input area.

more genetic, more better:

html:

```
<input type="text" class="entry"/>
<input type="text" class="entry"/>
```

javascript:

```
var div = $('div').hide();
var $entry=$('.entry');

$entry.keyup(function() {
    var $entryMatch=$entry.filter(function(){
           var value = $(this).val();
           if (['6','7'].indexOf(value)>-1) {
               return true
           } else {
              return false;
           }   

   });
    if ($entryMatch.size()==$entry.size()) div.show();
    else div.hide();




});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P69Vg/15/)